# How to split python list into segments based on elements' attributes?

Tags: python

I have a list like:

```
[
    {'p': 0},
    {'p': 1},   
    {'p': 1},
    {'p': 0},
    {'p': 0},
    {'p': 2}            
]
```

I want to split it into segments based on attribute p, so the result would be:

```
[[{'p':0}], [{'p':1}, {'p':1}], [{'p':0}, {'p':0}], [{'p':2}]]
```

Comment: Your final structure isn't valid, are these in a list ? Resulting in a 2D list ,

Comment: [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned you can use `itertools`:

```
import itertools

list_p = [
    {'p': 0},
    {'p': 1},
    {'p': 1},
    {'p': 0},
    {'p': 0},
    {'p': 2}
]

list_p_groups = []

for key, group in itertools.groupby(list_p):
    list_p_groups.append(list(group))
for item in list_p_groups:
    print(item)
```

Outputs:

```
[{'p': 0}]
[{'p': 1}, {'p': 1}]
[{'p': 0}, {'p': 0}]
[{'p': 2}]
```